# Cronjob taking a screenshot every hour with scrot

Tags: linux, bash, cron

One of my users needs a webpage screenshoted every hour. I was able to find a utility called scrot and it was easy setting up a cronjob to run every hour.

My issue is it takes a screenshot of both monitors and the way X server display is setup on our mint desktop machines, doing `Display:=0` is not an option because they are both under the same screen.

Digging deeper I found that scrot has an interactive option that allows you to select a screen (which wouldnt work for me since it has to be automatic) and also a currently focused option, which could potentially work but I cant find a way to focus the chrome window in cli that I need a screenshot of.

Any ideas with regards to focusing in the script or a different/better solution, would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why are you taking a screenshot, rather then simply dumping the html content of the relevant page every hour using curl or wget or the like?

Comment: See this [link](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/taking_a_screenshot#Screenshot_of_multiple_X_screens). Especially the part "Screenshot of multiple X screens".

Comment: The problem X screens is that both monitors run off of one X screen.

Comment: @davidgo the way website is written, it doesnt actually download the data. I just tried and it just downloads the index.html file. The data is probably dynamically generated.

Comment: @thermobeelearns  - what you are saying implies a lack of understanding of how http/html works. CURL can be customised to provide any data a web browser can - so unless it's hidden behind a capcha or equivalent test, curl can be programmed to get it as if it's the browser. That the server is dynamically content is irrelevant.

Comment: Your assertion that `DISPLAY=:0` won't work seems curious. Did you misspell it when experimenting (it needs to be all uppercase) or can you explain which `DISPLAY` values the different screens are on? I'm thinking you'd get the first one with `DISPLAY:0.0` and perhaps the second one with the same value but a different region of the virtual screen.

Comment: @davidgo is there an article you suggest for that CURL functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently there are other tools much better suited to your task.

### pageres-cli

NodeJS tool. install with:

```
sudo npm install -g pageres-cli
```

then simply:

```
pageres-cli google.com
```

### Firefox

From firefox 57, just do:

```
firefox -screenshot google.png google.com --window-size=1366,768
```

### cutycapt

Install (on ubuntu):

```
sudo apt install cutycapt
```

Run with:

```
cutycapt --url=google.com --out=google.png --min-width=1366 --min-height=768
```

I personally prefer the firefox method, because it is an almost omnipresent app